# Shift Index References in Table after Removing Row

Tags: jquery

We have a table with elements having an index on every Label/Input and TR ID, and a Remove button. When Remove is clicked, that row is deleted, and all the references below have to be shifted by 1 upward (-1).

We can try to figure out the manual shifting, but is there an easier way?

Affected Index-Including Items: TR, Every Label ID, Every Input ID, Every Input Name

HTML:

```
<tr id="period0">
   <td>
      <label for="budgetPeriod0">Enter the Budget Period number.</label>
      <input id="budgetPeriod0" name="name_period_0" />
   </td>
   <td>
      <label for="amount0">Enter the amount.</label>
      <input id="amount0" name="name_amount_0">
   </td>
</tr>
```

jQuery Delete TR (implemented) Shift (Not Implemented):

```
   removeRecord : function(index) {
          var v= "tr:eq("+index+")";
          $("#incomeTable >tbody").find(v).remove();

          var id = "#period"+index; 
          $(id).nextAll().each(function(i){
                 //shifting logic goes here

          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you are calling remove.  I would just reindex the whole table on removal of a row...

It does strike me as odd that the index is built into your id/names.

```js
$(function() {
  reindex();
});

function removeRecord(index) {
  var v = "tr:eq(" + index + ")";
  $("#incomeTable >tbody").find(v).remove();

  reindex();

}

function reindex() {
  var $row;
  $.each($("#incomeTable>tbody>tr"), function(idx, elem) {
    $row = $(elem);
    $row.attr("id", $row.attr("id").replace(/\d+/, idx));
    $.each($row.find("[for]"), function(i, label) {
      $(label).attr("for", $(label).attr("for").replace(/\d+/, idx));
    });
    $.each($row.find("[id]"), function(i, input) {
      $(input).attr("id", $(input).attr("id").replace(/\d+/, idx));
    });
    $.each($row.find("[name]"), function(i, input) {
      $(input).attr("name", $(input).attr("name").replace(/\d+/, idx));
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="incomeTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="period0">
      <td>
        <label for="budgetPeriod0">Enter the Budget Period number.</label>
        <input id="budgetPeriod0" name="name_period_0" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="amount0">Enter the amount.</label>
        <input id="amount0" name="name_amount_0">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="period0">
      <td>
        <label for="budgetPeriod0">Enter the Budget Period number.</label>
        <input id="budgetPeriod0" name="name_period_0" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="amount0">Enter the amount.</label>
        <input id="amount0" name="name_amount_0">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="period0">
      <td>
        <label for="budgetPeriod0">Enter the Budget Period number.</label>
        <input id="budgetPeriod0" name="name_period_0" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="amount0">Enter the amount.</label>
        <input id="amount0" name="name_amount_0">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```